How to set a CustomLogin Path in Spring Security?
I am using springboot and spring security for a web app, my user login works fine with the default login page, and also works if I use a custom login.html with the following code.
 http.formLogin(form ->{
            form.loginPage("/login").permitAll();
            form.defaultSuccessUrl("/files");

but If I set an different path like:
form.loginPage("/signin").permitAll();

Controller for "Custom" Login URL:
 @GetMapping("/signin")
    public String getSingIn(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("user", UserDTO.builder().build());

        return "login";


    }

The login form works, but I am unable to authorize on it. I just redirect to the login page again ("/signin")
<body>
<h1>Please Log In</h1>

<form method="POST"   th:action="@{'/login'}">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

I just wanted to know if I am doing something wrong or if it has to be always /login for the login form?

In your case, you are trying to use custom login path, which is not a static page, but MVC URL. In that case, I guess spring boot assumes the login processing URL to be same as the custom MVC URL provided in the formlogin configuration.
So, you have to tell spring boot to keep the login processing URL to be same as the default one or you can customize that too.
In your case, the modified spring security configuration would be as below:-
 http.formLogin(form ->{
        form.loginPage("/signin").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll();
        form.defaultSuccessUrl("/files");

Conversely, you also have the option to change the form login POST path as:- <form method="POST" th:action="@{'/signin'}">
